# Existence of a Section in Group Extension

Tags: group-theory, group-extensions

If $$ 1 \rightarrow A 
\rightarrow E \rightarrow G \rightarrow 1 $$ is an extension of of G by A, and we can find an isomorphic copy of $$G$$ in E, does the sequence automatically split? How would one show that this isomorphism, composed with $$ \pi:E \rightarrow G $$ is the identity on G? Thanks!

Comment: You write "... an isomorphic copy of $G/A$ ...", do you mean "... an isomorphic copy of $G$ ..."?

Comment: Sorry, that is indeed what I meant.

Comment: No. This already fails for the smallest interesting extension, namely $1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$.